# Load balancer for solrcloud

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We are hitting one of the solr instances in solrcloud architecture directly from a .Net application. If that instance is down, then the request need to be served by another live instance. This is possible with load balancer. What options are available for this and which can be used best? Solr cloud is in Windows. Please suggest since Solrj is not being used here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any load balancer would do. We are using nginx without trouble.

If you need something analogous to SolrJ, nothing stops you from writing some .Net code that queries zookeeper about status of different collection/shards etc. You put it in a library and can use it from your .Net code transparently. As a bonus you could get less roundtrips between Solr nodes as you could find out which is the shard a doc needs to go to, and send updates always to the shard leader.